# Hardening SSH security on a Debian 9 server

Tags: hardening, openssh, debian

I am running the following version of GNU/Linux Debian:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

says:

> ```
> Debian GNU/Linux 9
> ```

Using the following kernel:

```
uname -r
```

says:

> ```
> 4.9.0-2-amd64
> ```

And running the following version of OpenSSH:

```
apt-cache policy openssh-server | grep Installed
```

says:

> ```
> Installed: 1:7.4p1-7
> ```

---

My intention is to **harden** a little one server's SSH security, since I need to have access from any IP, even from any VPN.

These steps I have done so far:

1. Disabling direct root access:

   ```
   cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep PermitRootLogin
   ```

   is set to:

   > ```
   > PermitRootLogin no
   > ```
2. Enforcing SSH protocol version 2:

   ```
   cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Protocol
   ```

   is set to:

   > ```
   > Protocol 2
   > ```
3. Changed port to a random one, which I will not write here, so say 12345:

   ```
   cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Port
   ```

   is set to:

   > ```
   > Port 12345
   > ```
4. I have punched hole in firewall for it:

   ```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -m comment --comment "ssh" -j ACCEPT
   ```
5. I have generated a new key of 8 kilobits length (I am aware of the CPU overhead and other disadvantages of such a large key):

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 8192
   ```
6. I have then verified the size matches:

   ```
   ll /home/fictional_user/.ssh/id_rsa*
   ```

   is as it should be, as well as the access rights:

   > ```
   > -rw------- 1 fictional_user fictional_group 6.3K Mar 16 11:53 /home/fictional_user/.ssh/id_rsa
   > -rw-r--r-- 1 fictional_user fictional_group 1.4K Mar 16 11:53 /home/fictional_user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   > ```
7. I have added this key and verified there is no other:

   ```
   eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   ssh-add
   ssh-add -l
   ```

   results in:

   > ```
   > 8192 SHA256:gibberish /home/fictional_user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
   > 8192 SHA256:gibberish fictional_user@fictional_computer (RSA)
   > ```
8. I have imported the key to two machines, which will be maintaining the server:

   ```
   ssh-copy-id fictional_user@public_ip -p 12345
   ```
9. Afterwards, I have disabled password authentication completely:

   ```
   cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep PasswordAuthentication
   ```

   is set to:

   > ```
   > PasswordAuthentication no
   > ```

**Question:** Did I forget on anything or this is maximum I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of things you *can* do:

- Set up a private key [that uses a key-stretching algorithm](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/new-openssh-key-format-and-bcrypt-pbkdf) to protect brute-forcing the passphrase.
- Configure `AllowUsers` in sshd so only named accounts can gain access
- Use fail2ban or [fwknop](http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/index.html) to further prevent outside attacks (remember that [CVE-2008-0166](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-0166) caused Debian users to generate only one of 32,767 possible keys)
- Actively monitor your machine for attacks

Comment: @Vlastimil along with those, how about ssh with 2-factor authentication? It uses the google Authenticator app. Check it out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Just a few thoughts:

- sshd supports tcpwrappers, this adds protection when your firewall is down.
- does your file system support attributes on those public keys? Rather make them as read-only as possible.
- consider ssh-keysigning to limit the time keys are usable.